# Face pattern for boxes in boxplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I would like to do something of the sort (using matplotlib):
[image]

(from [Colorfill boxplot in R-cran with lines, dots, or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423115/colorfill-boxplot-in-r-cran-with-lines-dots-or-similar))

I saw some info about hatch(ing)? But I really can't make heads or tails on how to use this.

Also I find myself wondering how can I change parameters like the possible attributes of a boxprop dict -- used in plt.boxplot(..., boxprops=boxpropsdict). Is it possible to just have a list of all the possible attributes for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The important aspect is to set `patch_artist=True` when calling `boxplot`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fake up some data
spread= np.random.rand(50) * 100
center = np.ones(25) * 50
flier_high = np.random.rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = np.random.rand(10) * -100
data = np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

# basic plot
bp = plt.boxplot(data, patch_artist=True)

for box in bp['boxes']:
    # change outline color
    box.set(color='red', linewidth=2)
    # change fill color
    box.set(facecolor = 'green' )
    # change hatch
    box.set(hatch = '/')

plt.show()
```

The basic plot example is taken from the [boxplot demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo.html). However, none of those examples set `patch_artist=True`. If that statement is omitted, you will get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no attribute 'set_facecolor'

The [boxplot demo 2](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html) shows in great detail, how rectangles can be fitted to the boxplot in order to obtain coloring. [This blog](http://blog.bharatbhole.com/creating-boxplots-with-matplotlib/) points to the option of the `patch_artist`.
For more ideas about hatches, refer to the [hatch demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hatch_demo.html). The example above produces this figure:

[image]